# Template parameter deduction based on supplied lambda

Tags: c++

I am exploring template parameter deduction in C++ and am currently facing the problem to deduce the parameter to a lambda and the return type of the method it's passed to as a parameter at the same time. I think it should be possible, since all the types are known at compile time, but I fail to find the solution.

Some my question is:

**Is it possible to change the template struct Action in such a way that the last line containing result3 =... will compile? What changes a necessary**

**Compiler: gcc 7.5 and gcc 12.1**

Thank you very much for your help!

```
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&Function::operator())> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
  typedef const std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> function;
};

template <typename Function>
typename function_traits<Function>::function to_function (Function& lambda) {
  return static_cast<typename function_traits<Function>::function>(lambda);
}
  

template<typename A>
struct Action{
  A a;
  Action(A const& a_) : a(a_){}

  //allows action<type>(auto a){...})
  template<typename B>
  Action<B> action(std::function<B(A const&)> const& f) const{
    return Action<B>(f(a));
  }

  //allows action([](A a){....})
  template<typename CallableT>
  auto action(CallableT const& f) -> decltype(auto){
    auto g = to_function(f);
    using TargetType = decltype(g(a));
    return action<TargetType>(g);
  }

  //How to combine both????
};

void useAction(){
  Action<int> a(10);
  //both is possible  
  auto result1 = a.action([](int a){return static_cast<double>(a);});
  auto result2 = a.action<double>([](auto a){return static_cast<double>(a);});

  //The following does not compile. Can it be made to compile?
  auto result3 = a.action([](auto a){return static_cast<double>(a);});
}
```

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question.

Comment: Types are not really known at compile type: one can easily write a lambda that returns different types depending on the type of its argument. `[](auto a)` results in a templated `operator()` in a lambda. So your only option here is to either fix the return type like `action<double>` or fix the argument type somewhere around `to_function` instead of deducing it so the compiler can choose appropriate lambda's implementation.

Comment: the errors I get happen long before `result3 =`, hence I have no clue what error you refer to. https://godbolt.org/z/hWxqaoadq

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If you comment out the result3 line it compile well

Comment: @yeputons I fail to see where the type information is missing. Since I am using a method on `Action<A>`  `[](auto a)` must translate to `[](A a)`. And the return type Action<B> must translate to whatever the lambda return which is fix. How could I fix the argument type around to_function to pass on that knowledge? That is kind of the problem I am having.

Comment: because now you changed the code. Please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: "[](auto a) must translate to [](A a)" no. It must not. A lambda with `auto` parameter has a templated `operator()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function::operator()` may be a template, in which case `&Function::operator()` will fail.

`Function::operator()` may be overloaded, in which case `&Function::operator()` will also fail.

A lambda with an `auto` parameter has a template `operator()`.

`struct function_traits` doesn't know and doesn't care about `Action<A>`. All it has is your lambda.

Get rid of `to_function` and associated machinery, you don't need them.

```
//    auto g = to_function(f); <--- not needed
using TargetType = decltype(f(a));
std::function<TargetType(A const&)> g = f;
```